# Why the below code is executing asynchronous

Tags: javascript

I have some doubts on this code, why the below code is print "end" before completing fetchData request. Javascript is not asynchronous. then why end method run before completing fetchdata

```js
function start(){
  console.log("start")
}
function fetchData(){
   fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
}
function end(){
  console.log("end")
}
start()
fetchData()
end()
```

Comment: `fetchData` returns immediately

Comment: JavaScript absolutely is asynchronous. It does not even have a blocking `sleep()` operation, only timeouts with callbacks.

Comment: `fetch` asynchronous. It returns a `Promise`. It does not wait for the response to arrive.

Comment: Javascript is synchronous except for ajax calls

Comment: @SinanBaymammadli There are many more exceptions than just "ajax calls".

Comment: @SinanBaymammadli that is oversimplification to the point of misinformation. There are other async operations, for example `setTimeout` and in Node.js file operations will be async, too. There are others, too, so it's not just AJAX

Answer (score 1):

Your fetchData() function is async. Check out the docks on  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

> The Fetch API provides a JavaScript interface for accessing and manipulating parts of the HTTP pipeline, such as requests and responses. It also provides a global fetch() method that provides an easy, logical way to fetch resources asynchronously across the network.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to return the promise from fetch and then *await* the fetchData,  in an async. function. Fetch returns a [*promise*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and returns immediately, we have to [*await*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the promise to ensure the order of calls is preserved.

```js
function start(){
  console.log("start")
}
function fetchData(){
   return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
}
function end(){
  console.log("end")
}

(async() => {
    start()
    await fetchData()
    end()
})();
```

The async/await pattern gives us asynchronous code that's a lot easier to read than having a bunch of callbacks, see [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Answer (score 0):

In this case the request is async. Reading the docs on fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API we can see:

> The fetch() method takes one mandatory argument, the path to the resource you want to fetch. It returns a Promise ...

Promises are async.

If you need to wait for the data, do something like Terry Lennox's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Requests in javascript are asynchronous. You can tell because of the promise it returns (thats why you are able to call `then` after fetch)
So fetch request is sent, then `end`  function gets called and whenever fetch returns it will output its result, thats why you see `end` printed before, cause for sure http requests is taking at least some miliseconds

Comment: `that's why you see end printed before, cause for sure http requests is taking at least some milliseconds`, even if the request doesn't take any time `end` will be printed first.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because fetch makes an asynchronous call. 
To get a clear understanding of how the JS event loop works, have a look at 
[JS event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)